# Use old legacy bitcoin private key generated from 2012 to generate a segwit address

Tags: address, segregated-witness, address-generation

The old legacy addresses starts with 1 and the new ones start with 3 and bc1. Can I use my old private key from 2012 to generate a bc1 address? And how so?

Comment: Why would you want that? You shouldn't reuse a key.

Comment: I just want to verify if an old btc private key generates a segwit address of bc1 and 3. I just want to understand if its possible or not.

Comment: There is no point in that. Use wallet software that supports segwit, and let it generate a new key. Why you'd voluntarily give up your privacy is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses beginning with a 3 generated using `addwitnessaddress` are called P2SH-P2WPKH addresses. That means it is a Pay-to-Witness-Public-Key-Hash (P2WPKH) script embedded in a Pay-to-Script-Hash (P2SH) address, which starts with a 3.

To restore from that private key, you should be able to just import the key into your wallet and call `addwitnessaddress` on it again. Note that `addwitnessaddress` is an experimental RPC call so the method to restoring may change in future, but you can always generate the corresponding public key hash (address) from the key, create a P2WPKH witness script for it, and wrap it in P2SH.